# How to SSH into a server and then connect to a port?

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, robo3t, studio3t

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that runs a MongoDB instance. This is happening on a remote server.

The port for MongoDB is not exposed to the internet.

I am trying to be able to connect to this MongoDB instance.

```
version: "2.1"
services:

  ...

  database:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
    - data:/data/db
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"

volumes:
  data:
    name: data
```

The config in Studio 3T is...
[image]
[image]

When I used the "Test Connection" feature...
[image]

> Connection failed.
>
> SERVER [example.com:22] (Type: UNKNOWN)  |_/ Database error
> (MongoInternalException): The reply message length 759714643 is
> greater than the maximum message length 33554432
>
> Details: Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view
> of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=example.com:22,
> type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
> exception={com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message
> length 759714643 is greater than the maximum message length
> 33554432}}]

The connection string is...

```
mongodb://example.com:22/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&3t.uriVersion=3&3t.connection.name=production&3t.ssh=true&3t.sshAddress=example.com&3t.sshPort=22&3t.sshAuthMode=password&3t.sshUser=root&3t.alwaysShowAuthDB=true&3t.alwaysShowDBFromUserRole=true
```

It worked when having the port exposed publicly to the internet, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! On the "Server" tab, I changed port 22 to 27017 and example.com to localhost, and it made it work. You're a super-hero. If you make an answer, I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect to port 22 but the MongoDB runs on port 27017. Port 22 is only used for the SSH tunnel.

Comment: A note if other people take a look at this. On the "Server" tab I also needed to change "example.com" to "localhost"